# tensorflow model.predict usage

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I am trying to predict a result with the model that i train. But i cant figure out how to give the parameters to model.predict()

here is the data set *data_norm.head()*

```
        T    Y    K    B   GS   GI   GD    U
3561 -0.2 -0.2 -0.1 -0.9 -0.7 -0.7 -0.7 -0.7
7538  0.3 -0.2 -0.1 -0.9  0.6 -0.6 -0.6 -0.7
3641 -0.1 -0.2 -0.1  1.2 -0.7 -0.7 -0.7 -0.7
5436  0.1 -0.2 -0.1 -0.9 -0.7 -0.7 -0.7 -0.7
2842 -0.2  3.4 -0.1  1.2 -0.7 -0.2 -0.3 -0.5
```

T,Y,K,B,GS,GI,GD are features.
U is the label.

this is how i train:

```
feature_columns = []

# Represent median_income as a floating-point value.
temp = tf.feature_column.numeric_column("T")
feature_columns.append(temp)

yagmur = tf.feature_column.numeric_column("Y")
feature_columns.append(yagmur)

kar = tf.feature_column.numeric_column("K")
feature_columns.append(kar)

bulut = tf.feature_column.numeric_column("B")
feature_columns.append(bulut)

gunesSure = tf.feature_column.numeric_column("GS")
feature_columns.append(gunesSure)

GunesIsima = tf.feature_column.numeric_column("GI")
feature_columns.append(GunesIsima)

gunesDirekt = tf.feature_column.numeric_column("GD")
feature_columns.append(gunesDirekt)

# Convert the list of feature columns into a layer that will later be fed into
# the model. 
my_feature_layer = tf.keras.layers.DenseFeatures(feature_columns)


# The following variables are the hyperparameters.
learning_rate = 0.002
epochs = 60
batch_size = 200

# Split the original training set into a reduced training set and a
# validation set. 
validation_split=0.3


label_name = "U"
# Discard any pre-existing version of the model.
my_model = gunesPanel.create_model(learning_rate, my_feature_layer)

epochs, mse = gunesPanel.train_model(my_model, data, epochs, 
                          label_name, batch_size)
```

this is how i try to predict so far:
(in `test_prediction` there is one raw of data from dataset)

```
testprediction = np.array(test_prediction)
prediction1 = my_model.predict(x={'T':test_prediction[0], 'Y':test_prediction[1], 'K':test_prediction[2],
                               'B':test_prediction[3], 'GS':test_prediction[4], 'GI':test_prediction[5], 
                               'GD':test_prediction[6]}, steps=7)
```

and i get this error;

```
    WARNING:tensorflow:Falling back from v2 loop because of error: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: (<class 'dict'> containing {"<class 'str'>"} keys and {"<class 'float'>"} values), <class 'NoneType'>
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-18-339c32031c29>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/TDG/Desktop/Projects/Post_Prototatype/Gunes-Panel/Software V1.0/temp.py', wdir='C:/Users/TDG/Desktop/Projects/Post_Prototatype/Gunes-Panel/Software V1.0')

  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/TDG/Desktop/Projects/Post_Prototatype/Gunes-Panel/Software V1.0/temp.py", line 134, in <module>
    'GD':test_prediction[6]}, steps=7)

  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 909, in predict
    use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)

  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_arrays.py", line 715, in predict
    x, check_steps=True, steps_name='steps', steps=steps)

  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 2472, in _standardize_user_data
    exception_prefix='input')

  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_utils.py", line 522, in standardize_input_data
    data = [standardize_single_array(x) for x in data]

  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_utils.py", line 522, in <listcomp>
    data = [standardize_single_array(x) for x in data]

  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_utils.py", line 444, in standardize_single_array
    if (x.shape is not None and len(x.shape) == 1 and

AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

Comment: please attach the full error code

Comment: I edited with full error output